# how to read images form inpustream to android

Tags: android, image

i have 2 applications. One application act as server and it is created in java and sends continuously screen shot of desktop by using the following code.

```
public void screenCap() throws IOException, AWTException{

        Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(lastXpos, lastYpos, 500, 500);
        img = robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);
        Robot robot=new Robot();
        OutputStream os = null;
        BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", os);
    }
```

The second application is Android application acts a client application and has to read continuously the above image stream from inputstream.

Could please help me to read the images from inputstream in the client application.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Bitmap decodeStream()` method of [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) Class.

```
public static Bitmap decodeStream (InputStream is)
Since: API Level 1
```

Decode an input stream into a bitmap. If the input stream is null, or cannot be used to decode a bitmap, the function returns null. The stream's position will be where ever it was after the encoded data was read.

**Example:**

```
    String urlOfBitmap = ""; // Url of inputstream
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urlOfBitmap).openStream();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: can you site an example sir ?

Comment: Look at this SO Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android

Comment: your inputstream url address.. Address of url where your bitmap placed on server..

Comment: sir can i add you on my email address. so can i ask on you,thanks

Comment: If you have any doubt. you can comment me using '@' before my username like - `@user370305` on any android question so I will try my best to solve it.

Comment: sir i cant seer you'r email address

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream in;                       
in = ...;
bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```